# jsch ChannelExec run a .sh script with nohup "lose" some commands

Tags: ssh, exec, jsch, nohup

I hava a .sh script which glues many other scripts, called by jsch ChannelExec from a windows application.

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("/foo/bar/foobar.sh");

channel.connect();
```

if I run the command like "nohup /foo/bar/foobar.sh >> /path/to/foo.log &", all the long term jobs(database operations, file processing etc.) seems to get lost.

checking the log file, only find those echo stuffs(before and after a long term operation, calculate running time etc.).

I checked the permissions, $PATH, add source /etc/profile to my .sh yet none of these works.

but when I run the command normally (sync run, print all echo outputs to my java client on  windows),all the things goes well.

it's a really specific prob. 
Hope someone with experience can help me out.

thank in advance.

Han

Comment: Are you sure that they get lost, or could it be that they simply are still running when you check the output?

Comment: Also, try the same with a stock `ssh` client to see if it is related to JSch (I suppose not).

Comment: hi. I can make sure that they are lost. Some records ought to be loaded into the database if they worked.

Comment: I tried to use ChannelShell to execute those commands, and everything goes well. After some test, I found I must wait on the client side for some commands to print outputs, even if I use nohup mode. I'll keep testing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved!

> A different issue that often arises in
>   this situation is that ssh is refusing
>   to log off ("hangs"), since it refuses
>   to lose any data from/to the
>   background job(s).[6][7] This problem
>   can also be overcome by redirecting
>   all three I/O streams.
>
> from
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

My prob is, psql and pg_bulkload print their outputs to err stream.

In my script, I didn't redirect err streams.

Everything went fine by also redirecting err streams to the same log file.

```
nohup foo.sh > log.log 2>&1 &
```

Thanks to Atsuhiko Yamanaka, he created a great [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), and Paŭlo Ebermann for the [documentation](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/).

Comment: `nohup foo.sh > log.log 2>&1 &` save me a whole day!