# jsch & nohup - program doesn't start

Tags: java, jsch, nohup

I want to start my program in the background using jsch and 'nohup with &' command. This is my code:

```
    String command = "sudo nohup -jar [path to my jar] &";
    try{
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(true);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect(); 
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }

            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
            }
        }
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As the output I get:

```
Connected
exit-status: 0
DONE
```

but the program is not started. Without '&' it works, but with it doesn't. The same situation is when I put nohup command into .sh script and then run it. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224694/jsch-channelexec-run-a-sh-script-with-nohup-lose-some-commands

Comment: @SreenathSoman it doesn't help

Comment: @peter Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

3 years later...

I've recently had the same problem.
I solved it by using:

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setPty(false);
```

and by redirecting the output stream.
It seems to me it depends on the program being executed. I had a different script that just slept and printed date to a file and it didn't need any redirect. Also it was independent of JSch. Using the command line ssh the problem also existed.

The command I actually wanted to execute needed its output stream redirected away from stdout. If redirecting the stdout alone does not work redirecting the error stream and closing the input stream with `<&-` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
String command = "sudo nohup -jar [path to my jar] &";
```

with this:

```
String command = "sudo nohup -jar [path to my jar]>out.log 2>&1 &";
```

Comment: Similar resolved issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224694/jsch-channelexec-run-a-sh-script-with-nohup-lose-some-commands