# Calling a script from Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, jsch

I have a java program that uses the JSch libraries.  I can successfully call scripts from it, but when calling one script I have that calls another script, it doesn't end up calling the other one.  I have tested it in command line and it works just fine.  I know I am calling the script correctly from Java because part of it executes.  The script is below.

```
MOVIE_ROOT="/path/to/Movies"
IMDB_SCRIPT="/path/to/imdb-lookup/imdb-mf.sh"
MOVIE_FOLDER="$1"
MOVIE_FILE="$2"
MOVIE_NAME=${MOVIE_FILE%.*};

# If there isn't any info for the movie
if [ ! -f "$MOVIE_ROOT/$MOVIE_FOLDER/$MOVIE_NAME.jpginfo" ] ; then
cd "$MOVIE_ROOT/$MOVIE_FOLDER"; $IMDB_SCRIPT -p -t "\"$MOVIE_NAME\"" > "$MOVIE_ROOT/$MOVIE_FOLDER/$MOVIE_NAME.mvinfo";
exit 0;
fi
cat "$MOVIE_ROOT/$MOVIE_FOLDER/$MOVIE_NAME.mvinfo";
exit 0;
```

I also know that imdb-mf.sh works as well.  I have echod out the line cd "$MOVIE_ROOT... and pasted that into command line and it works fine.  The only time it doesn't work is when I run the script from Java.  All the scripts have correct permissions set and are chmod +x. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: And how are you running it from java?

Comment: Sounds like a stream redirections issue, the second script does not get a proper terminal to talk to and does not get executed, someone had similar problem before, try adding nohup and rediecting the script output to a single file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224694/jsch-channelexec-run-a-sh-script-with-nohup-lose-some-commands

hope this helps